# Error loading cx_Oracle : No module named 'cx_Oracle' in WINDOWS

Tags: python, django, oracle, visual-studio, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database with Django using Visual Studio 2015.
I get the following error:

> improperlyConfigured: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Note:

- `cx_Oracle` works perfectly in python
- Already have the latest `cx_Oracle` installed
- Tried installing Oracle Instant Client 12.1 and set its `PATH` in the environment variable

Can anyone help with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain there's only one install of Python on that Windows box? Or could there be multiple installs in different places?

Comment: Yes. I have only one version of python. (Python 3.4)